# How to increment the value in catch block?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm newbie to programming. Here is my scenario. I am testing a site. If some link is not founnd, it should go to catch block and move to next step. If it fails in k loops, it should do k++; not i++; or  j++; . If it fails in j loop, it should increment j value not i value or k value. How to do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchElementException {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    String links[] = new String[10];
    links[0] = "link1";
    links[1] = "link2";
    links[2] = "link3";
    links[3] = "link4";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    while (i < 4) {
        try {
            driver.get(links[i]);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'image')]")).click();
            while (j < 5) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'header')]")).click();
                while (k < 8) {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'title')]")).click();
                    k++;
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            // How to increment the  value of i or j or k
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the same way you do it in while loop i++, j++ k++

Comment: I think you're missing what the OP is asking. Notice there are 3 loops, each one has a different letter. If it fails in the `k` loop, the OP wants to increment that specific variable. Not the others.

Comment: @Gaskoin Can you explain it more clearly? Example pls..

Comment: Have a `char` variable at the top (`char currentLoop = 'i';)`. Once you enter each loop, store the appropriate char. Then in your `catch`, do a check like `if (currentLoop== 'k') {k++;}`

Comment: @Ascalonian you are right. Hideandseek - you should track in which loop you are, or not do nested loops

Comment: Can you share sample code ... I'm just learning..

Comment: @Hideandseek -   Done. Provided an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your code, have:

```
char currentLoop = 'i';
```

Then immediately after each while-loop declaration, set the value accordingly, like so:

```
while (i < 4) {
    currentLoop = 'i';
    ...

    while (j < 5) {
        currentLoop = 'j';
        ...

        while (k < 8) {
            currentLoop = 'k';
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the catch do:

```
if (currentLoop == 'i') {
    i++;
}else if (currentLoop == 'j') {
    j++;
}else if (currentLoop == 'k') {
    k++;
}
```